# Problem with ui:inputText and ui:inputNumber : maxlength and restrict some characters

Tags: lightning-aura-components, inputfield, ui

I have to use an input field, ideally an `ui:inputNumber`, so the user can only enter numbers. But I also need to put a `maxlength` on this field and this attribute does not work on `ui:inputNumber`.

The attribute `maxlength` works with the field `ui:inputText` but the user can also enter letters etc. So if I use this field I need to put a restriction on the field if the user enter a letter.

Do you know how to make one or the other way to make this field ?

Comment: This is a HTML5 native feature, don't think we need to do some kind of workaround for such basic feature. added an [idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000cRMPQA2).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well with a little bit of code you can achieve this. You need to use maxlength attribute to restrict the length and following approach for number only validation.

Have an attribute bound to your inputText

```
<aura:attribute name="inputN" type="String"/>
<ui:inputText value="{!v.inputN}" keypress="{!c.validate}" keyup="{!c.validate}" keydown="{!c.validate}"  updateOn="keypress, keyup, keydown"/>
```

In your controller, write validate function:

```
validate  : function(component, event, helper) {
        var inp = component.get('v.inputN');
        if(isNaN(inp))
            component.set('v.inputN', inp.substring(0, inp.length - 1));
    }
```

It will on press of each key, check if the whole text is number of not, if not will remove the last entered character.

In case of validating maxlength using ui:inputNumber,

```
<aura:attribute name="inputN" type="Decimal"/>
    <ui:inputNumber value="{!v.inputN}" keyup="{!c.validate}"  updateOn="keyup"/>
```

Js function:

```
validate  : function(component, event, helper) {
        var inp = component.get('v.inputN');
        if(inp.length > 2)
        {
            component.set('v.inputN', parseFloat(inp.substring(0, 2)));
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks it works well, but is it possible to use the same "trick" with an ui:inputNumber to truncate the number that the user put, for replace the lack of maxlength ?

Comment: I try something like that but it does not work : `limit  : function(component, event, helper) {
  var max_chars = 2;
  var input = component.get('v.number');

    if(input.length > max_chars) {
   component.set('v.number', input.substr(0, max_chars));
    }
 }`

Comment: Umm.. It does work. use input.substring, not input.substr

Comment: I try to replace with substring but I am still able to put more than 2 characters in the field

Comment: Ya I just did a POC, you need to change the attribute & ui:inputNumber & JS function. I have updated the answer

Comment: Thank you it works perfectly ! (So I guess the substring does not work with a decimal attribute)